# How are strings compared in haskell?

Tags: string, haskell, comparison

I just started studying Haskell and I'm reading a book called: Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!

In chapter 2, there is something I don't get.

When I am comparing two strings using the ">" operator for ex:

```
ghci> "Abrakadabra" < "Zebra"

True
```

I don't understand why it returns true. I tried to analyze this based on characters being ASCII, but I still don't understand why.
What I thought is that we compare the number of characters in the string, but this example changed how I understood it in the first place.

Could someone please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is lexicographic ordering, which is what you should expect if you look something up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

It's not comparing the length of the word. It's looking at the alphabetical order, A before Z.

Answer (score 1):

You have a answer by using GHCI :

```
Prelude> "a" > ""
True
Prelude> "a" > " "
True
```

and

```
Prelude> compare "a" ""
GT
Prelude> compare "a" " "
GT
```

The character 'a' is greater than space and nothing